# Passing on a Multi-Dimensional Array to another Method in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have `numbers[x][y]` and `int pm2 = 0;`. Is there a way to pass on this Mult-Array onto `public static boolean checkNumber(int[] list, int num)`? <- the parameters has to be used this way.

I invoked `checkNumber(numbers[x][y], pm2);`

I need to use the checkNumber method to check if a number has already been entered and returns true if the number is present and false if number is absent.

I am allowed to use multiple methods thought so I did have an idea of doing `numbers[x][0]` , `numbers[x][1]` etc, etc and invoking them into multiple `checkNumber()` methods. I was just wondering if there's a shorter way.

Comment: what language? please add the appropriate tag to your question

Comment: If the method accepts a 1D array, then you can't send it a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

> I was just wondering if there's a shorter way.

No there isn't.  The Java language doesn't support any kind of array "slicing", and you can't subvert the type system to allow you to refer use an array with a different type to what it really has.

You need to implement your idea of iterating the `int[]` component array of the `int[][]`, passing each one to `checkNumber(int[], int)`.  Something like this:

```
  for (int[] subarray : numbers) {
      checkNumbers(subarray, pm2);
  }
```

Comment: But you should be able to pass `numbers[x]` instead of `numbers[x][y]`. Then in the implementation of `checkNumber` you could iterate over all the numbers in the `int[]` array argument.

Comment: Through `numbers[x]` I can check the values of `numbers[x][0] , numbers[x][1]`? Is this what you're saying?

Comment: @JakeMitchell - That is true.  However, this is the solution that the OP already proposed; i.e. the one that he thinks is "not short enough".

Comment: Yes, @MarkBenabese. If you passed `numbers[x]` as the first argument to `checkNumber`, then within the `checkNumbers` implementation you'd access `numbers[x][i]` using `list[i]`. To iterate through every number there would be two `for` loops, the outer one as @StephenC describes and the inner one _inside_ the `checkNumber` implementation.

Comment: In C-ish languages you can index into a multi-dimensional array using a single indexer `[i]`, but that's not supported (or at least very unusual) in Java.

Comment: @JakeMitchell - It is definitely not supported in Java.  In Java a 2-D array is an array of objects, where each object is a 1-D array.

Answer (score 0):

You have single dimensional array as parameter.
So you have to pass one at a time probably in loop.

Comment: So if checkNumber(int[][] list, int num) this would work? And to pass it one by one, how do I code this in the loop?

Comment: checkNumber(int[][] list,int num) allows you to send complete 2D array at once for processing. If you don't wish to change method use  for(int i=0;i<y;i++){ checkNumber(numbers[x][i],pm2);}.

Comment: I don't quite understand this. You want me to use this for loop in the main method and invoke `checkNumber` in the for loop? You have `numbers[x][i]` in the parameter, doesn't this mean I'm still sending a 2D array?

Comment: Sorry coding error.User for(int i=0;i<x;i++){checkNumber(numbers[i],prm2);}

Comment: And this will allow me to check through the elements in `numbers[x][y]`? Sorry so many questions.

Comment: Yeah.Sending numbers[i] allows you to treat 2d array as individual 1d arrays.Free feel to ask any more doubts.

Comment: In `i < x` what is `x`? I have already initialized `int x = 0;` at the start.

Comment: x is the number of rows in the 2d array.For example - int arr[3][2]={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}.you have 3 rows i.e x and two columns i.e y.Passing arr[0] will mean passing {1,2}.